# Export data from database into excel file

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have code for export data into excel file. When I export excel file then excel file comes error while opening.

[image: this is error]

> The file format and extension of 'Farmer_Sample (4).xls' don't match.
>   The file could be corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its source,
>   don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway ?
>
> (Yes)(No)(Help)

This is code:

```
public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
    {
        var data = db.farmerSample.ToList();
        GridView gridview = new GridView();
        gridview.DataSource = data;
        gridview.DataBind();

        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename = Farmer_Sample.xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.Charset = "";

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                // render the GridView to the HtmlTextWriter
                gridview.RenderControl(htw);
                // Output the GridView content saved into StringWriter
                Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: You'd be better off posting the text from the error rather than such a large image which is mostly empty space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You are getting warning Message just because the file is genrated is
>   not real xls file... In your code sample...GridView RenderContol only
>   Genrate's HTML table.

**For Solution...You can use ClosedXML Library..and 3rd Party Reference Tools..**

*Or you can refer this Link*

https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Solution-ASPNet-GridView-Export-to-Excel-The-file-you-are-trying-to-open-is-in-a-different-format-than-specified-by-the-file-extension.aspx